# Error while running sql query

Tags: sql-server

I am seeing error while running below SQL query. Can some one please suggest the reason ?

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

select 100 * count(column_name) / count(*) from <table_name>
```

Also, when I run below query, I see output as 1. So, 1 * 100 should still be 100 and not sure of the reason for above error.

```
select count(column_name) / count(*) from <table_name>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I should have run below query (with a '(' and ')' for counts output):

```
select 100 * (count(column_name) / count(*)) from <table_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason of the error is caused by a calculated column value that exceeds the column's specified size. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163363(v=sql.105).aspx

```
select count(column_name) / count(*) from <table_name>
```

But COUNT() returns int and int / int would be always 0 then I suggest convery your count to float etc.

Like this

```
select round(cast(count(column_name) as float) / count(*),2) from <table_name>
```

Comment: He wants to count all `column_name` values, doing a `DISTINCT` will change it's logic.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT()` returns an `int` data type, which is capped at 2.147.483.647. If the result of `COUNT()` for whichever query you are doing is higher than that, then the arithmetic overflow pops up.

`COUNT_BIG()` works in the same way and returns a `bigint` data type, which should solve this overflow. Replace your `COUNT()` with `COUNT_BIG()`.

```
select 100.0 * count_big(column_name) / count_big(*) from <table_name>
```

You should also prevent division by 0, if it might be possible for your data.

```
select 
    100.0 * count_big(column_name) / NULLIF(count_big(*) , 0)
from 
    <table_name>
```

Comment: your query quarantiees return 0